# when i use AVAssetWriterInput, the value of readyForMoreMediaData is always is NO, but why?

Tags: avfoundation

when I use AVFoundation to record video, the video is no audio track, what happened this code?the value of readyForMoreMediaData is always return no, the method 'appendSampleBuffer:'is not to execute...??

```
1.
AVAssetWriterInput *audioWriterInput = [self audioWriterInput];
if ([self.assetWriter canAddInput:audioWriterInput]) {
    [self.assetWriter addInput:audioWriterInput];
}
2.
- (AVAssetWriterInput *)audioWriterInput {
    NSDictionary *audioCompressionSettings =
  @{
        AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey:@(28000),
        AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @(1),
        AVSampleRateKey : @(22050)
  };
    AVAssetWriterInput *audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:audioCompressionSettings];
    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    self.audioWriterInput = audioWriterInput;
    return audioWriterInput;
}
3.
- (void)appendingAudioSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
    // readyForMoreMediaData is always return NO
    if(self.audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
        BOOL success = [self.audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"");
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `startSessionAtSourceTime:` on your asset writer before you try to append the first sample buffer?

Comment: yeah, I calling `startSessionAtSourceTime ` like this `- (void)startWriter {
    NSLog(@"[LEAIVideo] startWriter currentSampleTime:%zd",self.currentSampleTime);
    [self.assetWriter startWriting];
    [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:self.currentSampleTime];
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such a silly boy. I used the getter method wrong!!!

Comment: audioWriterInput is self. audioWriterInput!!

Comment: - (AVAssetWriterInput *)audioWriterInput {
    NSDictionary *audioCompressionSettings =
  @{
        AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey:@(28000),
        AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @(1),
        AVSampleRateKey : @(22050)
  };
    AVAssetWriterInput *audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:audioCompressionSettings];
    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    self.audioWriterInput = audioWriterInput;
    return audioWriterInput;
}